# Improving performance of mouseover event in EaselJS

Tags: createjs, easeljs

From the manual:

> The latter four events have some overhead associated with them, so you
>   need to enable them with stage.enableMouseOver(frequency). The
>   frequency parameter indicates how many times per second EaselJS should
>   calculate what is currently under the pointer. A higher number is more
>   responsive, but also more computationally expensive.

I need to enable a mouseover functionality only on a certain class of objects on my otherwise crowded stage. Is there a way to enable the mouseover checking only for certain objects as opposed for the whole stage? Or is EaselJS only checking objects with a "mouseover / mouseout, and rollover / rollout" listener? What about the pointer property - it works only if enableMouseOver is enabled - is that checked for all objects or only for those with pointer property other than default?

Is EaselJS internally doing some space partitioning like k d trees to boost the performance?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent any object from receiving a mouse event by setting `mouseEnabled=false`.

```
myBitmap.mouseEnabled = false;
```

If you have a large amount of items (such as particles), make sure they are in a container, and set `mouseEnabled` AND `mouseChildren=false` on the container, and the Stage will not check any of the container's children.

```
myContainer.mouseEnabled = myContainer.mouseChildren = false;
```

If you still want to know when a container's general area is clicked, you can swap out the default mouse behaviour with a `hitArea`, which is used in place of its actual contents.

```
var hitArea = new createjs.Shape();
hitArea.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
myContainer.hitArea = hitArea;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Disabling mouseEnabled/mouseChildren is a good idea - if the 4 event types are in fact processed in objects with no listeners as is part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. For improving the performance i used cache if any object is static
2. I used mouseEnabled =false;
3. I did not render any text or images inside the canvas i used mix of
   angular or plain javascript to render the dom element